# Extending Angular2 Http doesn't inject service

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ionic2

Can't seem to figure this out. I have a custom class that extends the built-in angular Http class.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    Http,
    ConnectionBackend,
    RequestOptions,
    RequestOptionsArgs,
    Request,
    Response
} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { OAuth } from './oauth.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {
    constructor(connectionBackend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private $oauth: OAuth) {
        super(connectionBackend, defaultOptions);
        debugger;
    }    
}
```

I then inject my `HttpService` into another class.

```
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class KateService {
    constructor(private $http: HttpService) {

    }
}
```

However, at the debugger statement that I have set in my `HttpService`, my `private $oauth: OAuth` is null. And when I look at the callstack, the calling method doesn't inject my OAuth service, just the two (connectionBackend, and defaultOptions).

I feel that it's treating my custom Http service like the built-in angular Http service. But I'm pretty new to Angular2 so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS` (import HttpModule), `OAuth`, and `HttpService`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpModule]
  providers: [OAuth, HttpService],
  ...
})
```

Comment: I should mention that this is an ionic2 application. I don't get access to NgModule in an ionic2 app (just a root component), so I have my component providers look like this `providers: [OAuth, HttpService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]` but it's still null

Comment: That would be equivalent. I don't see why it wouldn't work. There were issues with DI and classes extending other classes. I don't know if they are fixed. As workaround you could embed `Http` instead of extending it. You would need to repeat the `get`, `post`, ... methods in your class and forward them to `this.http`. To check if it is related to extending other classes you could just remove `extends Http` and `super(...)` and see if all parameters are injected this way.

Comment: This works. Instead of extending, I injected both my Http, and OAuth service, and both work as expected. Either they have bugs to work out, or perhaps my providers are not setup correctly. Either way, I can continue onward. Thanks